# How to Retrieve Only Year in servlets while having resultset from the database

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have to retrieve the `Year(datepaid)` from the database. What method should I use to get `Year(datepaid)`

I have tried using the method `getDate("column name")`, it is showing error because it is looking for date format from the database but here I'm retrieving only Year 2020 which is not in the date format.

`resultSet.getDate("column name")` is not working, what method should I use now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special method to retrive YEAR type column. You can just use `resultSet.getString` or `resultSet.getInt` to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the Database your column is of TYPE DATE/TIMESTAMP. And getDate should retrieve the complete date. So in java you can use the next code to properly access the year:

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTime(date); //date = complete date from the DB
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

If in your DB the column of the date just have the year (Ex: 2020, 2019), could be an integer or a string. So `resultSet.getString` or `resultSet.getInt` would work.